# URL Redirection not working Android Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use the sample Android AppAuth application with B2C Tenant.

I am getting "ERR: UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" after being redirected from a sign in/sign up flow. The response token is getting generated.

appAuthRedirectScheme provided as suggested in microsoft azure website.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "Native Client" switch is turned to "Yes". Your Redirect URL should have a unique, custom scheme in order for your Android application to capture the callback.

Please check the example in this [Github sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth/) to ensure that you have set it up properly.

You need to ensure that all of the references in your code match what you have in the app registration.